# How to play a video from Amazon S3 server in IOS?

Tags: ios, video, amazon-s3, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working on IOS Application which Uploading the Video at Amazon S3 server and then i need to play that video in my Iphone with progressive download.(I dont want to download the Video in iphone).
I have tried with this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://BuccketName.s3.amazonaws.com/MovieName.mp4"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [moviePlayer setContentURL:url];


    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Now My Problem is Its not plying the Video From Url and Giving me Error as follows :

```
2014-03-28 12:13:35.327 Streamingplayer[214:60b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Can anyone please Guide me How can i play a video from Amazone S3 Server URL ...

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question as you are not intending to stream but to use progressive download.

Comment: thanks ..i have updated

Comment: Facing similar issue.. Can you please help?

Comment: what my problem was the video is not public from amazon server

Comment: @BhavikKama is there some elegant way to solve this? Because this way takes too much of network and streams snailpace slow